# cc_binary() cannot be called during the analysis phase

Tags: bazel

I've tried to convert a Bazel macro to a rule, so it's parsing is done now on analysis time rather than on loading time, this makes calling `native.cc_binary` impossible to do

```
def _emcc_binary(ctx):

    includejs = False
    includehtml = False
    linkopts = list(ctx.attr.linkopts)
    linkopts.append("-s EXTRA_EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS='[\"ccall\", \"cwrap\"]'")

    if ctx.attr.name.endswith(".html"):
        basename = ctx.attr.name[:-5]
        includehtml = True
        includejs = True
    elif ctx.attr.name.endswith(".js"):
        basename = ctx.attr.name[:-3]
        includejs = True
    outputs = []
    if includejs:
        outputs.append(basename + ".js")
        if ctx.attr.wasm:
            outputs.append(basename + ".wasm")
        if ctx.attr.memory_init_file:
            outputs.append(basename + ".mem")
        if ctx.attr.worker:
            outputs.append(basename + ".worker.js")
            linkopts.append("--proxy-to-worker")
            

    if includehtml:
        outputs.append(basename + ".html")
    if not ctx.attr.wasm:
        linkopts.append("-s WASM=0")
        linkopts.append("--memory-init-file %d" % ctx.attr.memory_init_file)

        if includejs:
            tarfile = ctx.attr.name + ".tar"

            # we'll generate a tarfile and extract multiple outputs
            native.cc_binary(name = tarfile, linkopts = linkopts, **ctx.attr.kwargs)
            native.genrule(
                name = "emcc_extract_" + tarfile,
                srcs = [tarfile],
                outs = outputs,
                output_to_bindir = 1,
                testonly = ctx.attr.kwargs.get("testonly"),
                cmd = """
              tar xvf $< -C "$(@D)"/$$(dirname "%s")
            """ % [outputs[0]],
            )
        else:
            native.cc_binary(name = ctx.attr.name, linkopts = linkopts, **ctx.attr.kwargs)
                # we'll generate a tarfile and extract multiple outputs

emcc_binary = rule(
    implementation = _emcc_binary,
    attrs = {
        "memory_init_file": attr.int(default = 0),
        "wasm": attr.bool(default = True),
        "worker": attr.bool(default = False),
        "srcs": attr.label_list(allow_files = True),
        "linkopts": attr.string_list(),
        "noop": attr.bool(default = False),
        "kwargs": attr.label_keyed_string_dict()

    },
)
```

Output:

```
cc_binary() cannot be called during the analysis phase ERROR: Analysis of target '//tests:hi.js' failed; build aborted: Analysis of target '//tests:hi.js' failed; build aborted
```

Answer (score 3):

Correct, rules cannot be called from the implementations of other rules. Typically the solution is to use both rules and macros, where the macro creates and wires up the other rules (including your custom Starlark rules) where necessary.

Looking over your code, it's not clear that you really need to change the macro to a rule. Might be helpful if you could describe your end goal (feel free to reach out to [bazel-discuss](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/bazel-discuss) if you'd like more help here). That said, if you really wanted, you can replace `native.genrule` with [actions](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/0.28.0/skylark/lib/actions.html) and `native.cc_binary` with [cc_common](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/0.28.0/skylark/lib/cc_common.html), which are designed to work with rules.